# Wordpress. Не находит файлы в папке wp-includes

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, почему не находит файлы в папке wp-includes, хотя физически они там есть. Делаю кастомную тему на основе underscores на localhost xampp.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если указанный путь скопировать и вставить в адресную строку браузера, файл откроется? или будет 404?

Comment: Вот что пишетNot Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.1.2 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: значит, путь неправильный, если по такому адресу не открывается js-файл. у Вас точно wp-includes лежит в корне localhost? или есть папка проекта, а уже в ней wp-includes?

Comment: Корень- это xampp->htdocs?

Comment: Дальше у меня три папки с разными проэктами, в первых двух ошибок никаких нет, а вот в третьем почему-то появляются...

Comment: деактивирую плагин woocommerce - ошибки уходят. Может это в последней обнове какие-то изменения приводят к ошибкам?

Comment: Ну, если есть такая зависимость от активации/деактивации woocommerce, то видимо в этом какая-то проблема, да